# WebView insert local image to html couldn't success?

Tags: html, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a WkWebView in my ViewController, I used webview load local html. The code is this:

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "editor", withExtension: "html") else {
        return
    }
webView.load(URLRequest(url: path))
```

1: I choose a image from photoLibrary, then I saved it to document's directory .

```
private func fileName() -> String {
    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd@HH-mm-ss"
    return "/" + formatter.string(from: date) + ".png"
}

func saveImage(_ image: UIImage) {
    guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) else {
        return
    }
    let directory = NSHomeDirectory().appending("/Documents")
    let path = directory.appending(fileName())
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
        try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: directory, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: path, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
    } catch {
        SHLog("saveImage: \(error)")
    }
}
```

2: I fetched the image path then I used the method of the webView to insert the image.

```
func evaluateJs(_ imagePath: String) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("insertImage('\(imagePath)')") { (response, error) in
    }
}
```

insertImage() is a method from the local js file, it can insert the image to html.

If I used the local imagePath, I couldn't insert image to html. But When I used the real url, it can work. I don't know the reason, anyone could help me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, @Jack Long, did you figure it out? I have same problem. Thx~

Comment: keep the html file and image below the same folder, it will solve this problem. you can see here [link](http://blog.csdn.net/longshihua/article/details/78008594)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely caused by WKWebViews security policies not allowing you access to the local folders of the application.

Check out the documentation for [WKWebView loadFileURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414973-loadfileurl). You should be able to pass either the documents directory or full image URL in the `allowingReadAccessTo` parameter which should let you access the images you want.

If you have a web url of the image, I would prefer to use the web URL anyway rather than trying to store and load the image locally. Your not using up storage in your documents directory and WKWebView is designed to load content from the web.

Comment: Thanks. I have a function that is use the webView load the local html. It is a rich text editor that can input text and image. So I need to insert image to html. As you mentioned, I used loadFileURL method, It still couldn't work. I also found some answers link , but it couldn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, assign baseURL your image file's parent folder firstly. Then insert the whole URL path in your html likes following.

```
<img src="/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C217F3BD-1A1B-438A-A436-D878411C7849/Documents/48C4B007-A950-46D2-A719-E025482710A0/images/79042B1F-E11C-42D1-8B49-DD3A0016F421.jpg"
```

Comment: you are right , keep html file and image in the same folder.

Comment: @Jack Long, Actually, my html file and image file in different folder.

Comment: I mean the html file and image file are below the baseURL.  Even if html file and image file is in different folder. It will be ok.

Comment: @Jack Long, Actually, my html file is in bundle and image file is below my app's sandbox's documents.

Comment: yeah, you can load the document path, it also can be a subfolder.